# Two Autofac containers competing in a single webrequest

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

A bit of a strange situation: I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that uses Autofac as its IoC container and that can be dropped into any existing MVC or WebForms application.

Everything works fine, except when the other application also uses Autofac. I've created a custom DependencyResolver wrapper that combines my application's AutofacDependencyResolver with DependencyReolver.Current of the other application (when set). Resolving of components just fails sometimes although I can see in the debugger that everything is properly registered.

I suspect that both inner resolvers are competing for a spot in the HttpContext.Items collection, but I can't get my finger behind the exact issue.

What would be the proper way to handle this situation?

Comment: You may need to provide some additional detail about some of your custom code and how you're setting things up. Is the web forms app using DependencyResolver for something? When you say you have "an MVC 3 application that uses Autofac... that can be dropped into any existing" application, what exactly is being "dropped in" and to where?

Answer (score 1):

You could isolate the configuration into a module. When you integrate one application into the other, register the module.